# Haskell ReaderT Env IO boilerplate

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have the following boilerplate that I do quite often, and would like to eliminate. It looks something like this:

```
type Configured = ReaderT Config

doSomething :: Configured IO Data
doSomething = do
   getMeta <- asks getMetaData
   meta <- liftIO getMeta
```

I'd like to reduce that to something like this:

```
doSomething = do
    meta <- find getMetaData
```

Unfortunately, I haven't fully wrapped my mind around monad transformers yet. What is the type of `find`? Is it `(Config -> IO Result) -> Result`? How do I write it?

Any tips / explanation to help me grok monad transformers are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time right now to explain this, but here's something: the type of `find` is `(Config -> IO Result) -> Configured IO Result` in your example and more generally `Monad m => (r -> m a) -> ReaderT r m a`. You can define it as `find = asks >=> lift`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done in a fairly mechanical fashion. Let's start with your original code:

```
doSomething = do
    getMeta <- asks getMetaData
    meta <- liftIO getMeta
    ...
```

Using [the third monad law](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Laws), we are allowed to move the part we want to extract into a do-block of its own:

```
doSomething = do
    meta <- do getMeta <- asks getMetaData
               liftIO getMeta
    ...
```

Next, we can just extract that subexpression and give it a name:

```
findMetaData = do getMeta <- asks getMetaData
                  liftIO getMeta

doSomething = do
    meta <- findMetaData
    ...
```

Finally, let's generalize it by replacing the explicit reference to `getMetaData` with a parameter:

```
find something = do x <- asks something
                    liftIO x

doSomething = do
     meta <- find getMetaData
     ...
```

Now, we can load it in GHCi and ask it to infer the type for us:

```
*Main> :t find 
find :: (MonadReader r m, MonadIO m) => (r -> IO b) -> m b
```

---

Optionally, we might want to clean it up a little and remove the dummy name `x`:

```
find something = ask >>= liftIO . something
```

To do this, I used [the definition of `asks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#asks) and [the desugaring rules for do-notation](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Comment: And one step further (as noted by Miikka) gives you "find = asks >=> liftIO". Thanks! Makes sense now.